# How to change fontsize of options in Material ui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

Hi i am using material table in my project and i want to know how to change font size of options in material ui autocomplete. Thank you

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },

];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use renderOptions, together with the component you want.

```
 <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={top100Films}
        renderOption={(option) => (
          <Typography style={{ fontSize: "1.5rem" }}>{option.title}</Typography>
        )}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, style: { fontSize: "1rem" } }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-leaf-bn7pk?file=/src/App.js:223-544)

[image: Normal Font]

[image: Big Font]

Comment: my bad, I thought you wanted input text. Please check my renderOptions props. I've edited my answer

Comment: This code will shows and empty dropdown. How can I fix this?

Comment: u using v5? this answer is for v4.

Comment: Yes it is v5. Is there way to fix this for v5?

Comment: create your own question

Comment: Created it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421320/how-to-change-options-font-size-in-material-ui-version-5-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Mui uses `ul li` html elements to render the autocomplete options, by overriding `renderOption` you can customize `li`s and their inner content as well (`ul` is already put by Mui) and set them your desired styles, classes, etc.

Use `renderOption` like this :

```
<Autocomplete
    id='combo-box-demo'
    options={top100Films}
    renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <li key={option} {...props}>
      <Typography style={{ fontSize: '1.1rem' }}>{option}</Typography>
      //<Typography variant='h6' >{option}</Typography>
      //<Typography className='font-large yourDesiredClass' >{option}</Typography>
    </li>
  )}
  />
```

Note that in above snippet, I emitted some of unmodified props like `style`, `renderInput`, etc to emphasize how to use `renderOption` prop, correctly and also for purpose of brevity.